# Python Django autocomplete light the results could not be loaded

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to add autocomplete light to my project, but I am not able to. If I want to find anything in the form it says: The results could not be loaded, TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable.  I am using Python version 3.7 and django-autocomplete-light version 3.3.5

The project is web app to track orders which are assigned to the users.

to the mysite/settings.py I added:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

'dal',
'dal_select2',
'crispy_forms',
'myapp',
```

to the mysite/myapp/urls.py I added:

```
path('autocomplete/', login_required(views.OrderAutocomplete.as_view()), name="autocomplete"),
```

to the base.html:

```
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and to the new_order.HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
{{ form.media }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

To the mysite/myapp/views.py I added:

```
class ObjednavkaAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Objednavka.objects.none()

        qs = Order.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

and to the mysite/myapp/forms.py I added:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_auto = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Order.objects.all(), widget = autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='autocomplete'))
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["user_auto"]
```

mysite/myapp/models.py:

```
from dal import autocomplete

class Order(models.Model):
   ...    
   user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class MyUser(models.Model):
   eid = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

I am sorry for posting so much code.

If I try to find a user on the webpage: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNSAH.jpg): [Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNSAH.jpg)

Comment: Can you add logs with `DEBUG = True` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if not self.request.user.is_authenticated()
```

With

```
if not self.request.user.is_authenticated
```

In django>2.0 it is attribute. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but did not help.

Comment: @pipikej Are you sure you provide valid code? In your `ObjednavkaAutocomplete` you returns `Objednavka` instances(actually `none()` of them), but filtering by `Order` model. And in your `urls.py` you use `OrderAutocomplete` not `ObjednavkaAutocomplete`.

Comment: The code is valid I tried to translate the word from czech language to the english and few of them I missed. Objednavka == Order

Comment: @pipikej I'm just copy your project and run it locally, problem was as I say in `is_authenticated()`. After i change it to `is_authenticated` it starts working.

Comment: @Johny Beehop I set wrong filter in the views.py Now it loads all the users but if I want to type in anything it shows again: The results could not be loaded. django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: myid, id, name, order, surname. But If I put to the widget any of the choices it shows classic roll down choice menu.

Comment: @pipikej can you share your filter?

Comment: qs = qs.filter(prijmeni__istartswith=self.q)

Comment: worked for me but I'm still trying to figure out why as the rest of my project uses is_authenticated():